# PHP Random Variable Names

Tags: php, forms, variables, generated

Hi I'm really new to programming I mean really new so before answering, think in the mind of a programming n00b! Anyway, more to the point in PHP I'm trying to create an account system so every time someone fills in an HTML form it automatically creates a new variable. The new variable would obviously be what they entered and possibly would be called something like $user147 for example. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I think your confused about variable scope - normally they last for less than the duration of the request and aren't shared between requests. PHP writes html.

Comment: I don't know what I'm getting confused with :/

Comment: Your question just doesn't make any sense. Please at least get some BASIC knowledge of the programming language you want to use, before asking things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a good start would be reading the manual. That's aside, you should learn about SQL and how to make and use tables.

My advice to you is this: get reading, try it out, if you get stuck along the way, come back here and ask. No one here will write code for you.

Comment: I'm not asking for code, all I want is to know how to randomly generate a variable name. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You're not making sense. How would a randomly named variable ever help you with a user registration system? You need a more permanent place (such as a database) to save the user details. The variable will not persist once the page is finished loading.

Comment: I suppose so. Thanks and sorry! By the way do you know any good database/SQL tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Probably bad practice, however what you are trying to do is possible:

```
$var = $_GET['user147'];
$$var = $var;
```

now you have a variable named $user147 that contains the string 'user147'

Answer (score 0):

Go to the PHP website and read about the $_REQUEST superglobal. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Don't use random variable names, as it is poor practice.